# SQL sort by closest string match in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a search parameter that I am trying to search on multiple columns using the `"Like % InputParam %"` pattern matching which gives me the following result. ie - Matching OrderID and Ref no to the input parameter.

Consider I have the following table -

```
OrderId  | Name | Ref No  |
12345    | XYZ  | 120545  | 
1205     | ABC  | 451003  |
00120505 | CDE  | 000174  |
```

Here OrderID, Ref no are strings and the input query = '1205'. I want the result to be sorted from the most matched to the least matched.

Where most matched is the most accurate match like 1205 = 1205 here
and Least matched is a substring like 00120505 = 1205.

Output -

```
OrderId  | Name | Ref no  |
1205     | ABC  | 451003  |
12345    | XYZ  | 120545  |
00120505 | CDE  | 000174  |
```

Comment: "Most matched" and "least matched" is vague and subjective, you need to specify it more clearly.

Comment: @PeterB Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what you mean by the distance between two strings. I'll use @peter-b 's definition in the example below. Once you know how to measure how close a string is to the search parameter, you can transpose the columns to rows with cross apply (LATERAL is the standard name), and use the min distance to order the rows.

```
with t (orderid, refno) as ( 
    select '12345','120545' 
    union all 
    select '1205','451003'
)
select t.orderid, t.refno
     , min(case when u.s = '1205' then 1
                when u.s like '1205'+'%' then 2
                when u.s like '%' + u.s + '%' then 3
                else 4
           end) as distance
from t
cross apply ( 
    select t.orderid 
    union all 
    select t.refno 
) as u (s)
group by t.orderid, t.refno
order by 3
;

orderid refno   distance
1205    451003  1 
12345   120545  2
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a172bbc5fed3631d94f539b4f01fabf7)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining a computed column e.g. **`MATCH_SCORE`** with a value that depends on comparisons between *`OrderId`* and the value you are looking for; and then use **`ORDER BY MATCH_SCORE`**.

Working example:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (OrderId VARCHAR(10), Name VARCHAR(10), RefNo VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('12345','XYZ','120545'), ('1205','ABC','451003'), ('00120505','CDE','000174')

DECLARE @v VARCHAR(10) = '1205'

;WITH data AS
(SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN OrderId = @v THEN 1
         WHEN OrderId LIKE @v + '%' THEN 2
         WHEN OrderId LIKE '%' + @v + '%' THEN 3
         ELSE 4
    END AS MATCH_SCORE
 FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY MATCH_SCORE
```

Output:

| OrderId | Name | RefNo | MATCH_SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1205 | ABC | 451003 | 1 |
| 00120505 | CDE | 000174 | 3 |
| 12345 | XYZ | 120545 | 4 |

I used a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to construct `data`, which defines a *temporary named result set* that is used by the `SELECT` that follows it.